# How to reset all states when property value is changed from javascript?

Tags: stenciljs

I am using stencil framework. In my component I am using different states to trigger different events. I am also updating the property value of component from javascript.

I would like to reset all states value and reload the component with updated property value. 
New property value is responsible for many actions like calling api, generating the cache key etc.

Can anyone suggest me the best approach to fulfill my requirement. Currently I am reset all the states in watcher method of property and call the componentWillLoad event but I am facing many issue in this approach.

Sample code

```
@Prop() symbol!: string;
  @Watch('symbol')
  symbolChanged(newSymbol: string, prevSymbol: string) {
    if (newSymbol && newSymbol !== prevSymbol) {
      this.resetStates();
    }
  }
  resetStates() {
   //Reset all state values here
    this.componentWillLoad();
  }
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to put too much logic into that component. Anyway, maybe it's easier to create a new component instance when the value changes? You can use a different `key` on your component to make sure the old one doesn't get reused (for info about `key` see https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx#loops).

Comment: @SimonHänisch by setting key property on each symbol change would work for me. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting key property on root element of render method would solve my issue like below code snippet.

```
 uniqKeyId = uniqid.get();

 @Prop() symbol!: string;
    @Watch('symbol')
    sysmbolWatcher(newSymbol: string, prevSysmbol: string) {
    if (newSymbol != prevSysmbol) {
       //update key attribute each switch of exchange
       this.uniqKeyId = uniqid.get();
       //Set default values based on properties as to consider this as fresh request.
       this.setDefaultValues();
    }
  }
```

And in render method like below

```
 render() {    
      return (    
        <section class="cid-minichart" key={this.uniqKeyId}>
            //Render markup
        </section>
      );
  }
```